# Area bounded by a curve

Tags: calculus, integration, area

Question: Find the area bounded by the curve $y$= $4$ $Tan{\frac{x}{2}}$, X-axis (or $y=0$), $x= {\frac{-π}{2}}$ and $x= {\frac{-π}{3}}$.

I am having a slight difference in the answer and I am not able to figure out why it's happening. I hope I get it resolved through this post.

My solution:

Sketch the graph first. For $y$= $4$ $Tan{\frac{x}{2}}$, lets check the periodicity.
Periodicity= $2π$, then for different values of x, the graph of $y$= $4$ $Tan{\frac{x}{2}}$ out to be:

[image]

Since periodicity =$2π$, so lets only take the portion of the graph from $x=-π$ to $x=π$.

[image]

We need to find the shaded area from $x=-\frac{π}{2}$ to $x=-\frac{π}{3}$. The following is the required area:

[image]

Shaded Area is:

$\int _{−π/2 }^{−π/3 }$ $4$ $Tan{\frac{x}{2}}$dx

= $8$ $ln|sec \frac{x}{2}|$ from $x=-\frac{π}{2}$ to $x=-\frac{π}{3}$

= $8$ ($ln|sec \frac{-\frac{π}{3}}{2}|$ - $ln|sec \frac{-\frac{π}{2}}{2}|$)

= $8$ $ln|\frac {sec \frac{-\frac{π}{3}}{2}} {sec \frac{-\frac{π}{2}}{2}}|$

= $8$ $ln|\frac {sec \frac{-π}{6}} {sec \frac{-π}{4}}|$

= $8$ $ln|\frac {sec \frac{π}{6}} {sec \frac{π}{4}}|$

= $8$ $\ln \left| \frac{\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}}{\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}} \right|$

= $8$ $\ln \left| \frac{2}{\sqrt{6}} \right|$

Now, the answer mentioned in the exercise is $8$ $\ln \left| \frac{\sqrt{6}}{2}\right|$ and this is true when:

$\int _{−π/2 }^{−π/3 }$ $4$ $Tan{\frac{x}{2}}$dx = $-8$ $ln|cos \frac{x}{2}|$ from $x=-\frac{π}{2}$ to $x=-\frac{π}{3}$

Why does this difference in answer occur? I think that it might be because the shaded area is below the X-axis and thus should come out to be negative and ultimately the value is taken ignoring the negative sign. Thus, $\int _{−π/2 }^{−π/3 }$ $4$ $Tan{\frac{x}{2}}$dx should be equal to $-8$ $ln|cos \frac{x}{2}|$ from $x=-\frac{π}{2}$ to $x=-\frac{π}{3}$ instead of $8$ $ln|sec \frac{x}{2}|$ from $x=-\frac{π}{2}$ to $x=-\frac{π}{3}$.

Is my interpretation and calculation correct? Please help with the problem regarding the difference in the answer. Is my reasoning correct for it? Looking forward to your response.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The integral you set up evaluates to a negative number. As you observed, the integrand is negative over the entire interval of integration, so the result *must* be negative.

But the area bounded by four curves is generally considered positive, and this problem is no exception to that rule.

If you consider the problem as a question of finding the area *below* the line $y = f(x) = 0$ and *above* the curve $y = g(x) = 4\tan\frac x2$, you would naturally set up the integral of $f(x) - g(x)$ over the interval $\left[-\frac \pi2,-\frac\pi3\right]$,

$$
\int_{-\pi/2}^{-\pi/3} \left(0 - 4\tan\frac x2\right)\mathrm dx.
$$

This integral will have a positive value.

Alternatively, you could observe that a vertical cross section through the region has length $-4\tan\frac x2$ (where the negative sign is needed because length is a positive quantity), and set up the integral that way.

In any case you should have a negative sign in the integrand.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the sign of the definite integral, it seems you are worried about the difference between the functions $-8 \ln |\cos(x/2)|$ and $8 \ln|\sec(x/2)|$.

Those are, in fact, equivalent since $- \ln z = \ln (z^{-1}) = \ln \frac{1}{z}$ for any $z$. Also, $\sec\theta = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}$. So
$$
8 \ln|\sec(x/2)| = 8 \ln\left|\frac{1}{\cos(x/2)}\right|
   =-8 \ln|\cos(x/2)|
$$

Comment: I was worried about the difference in the final answer. As I have mentioned, using $−8$ $ln|cos \frac {x}{2}|$ gives the number $-8$ $ln \frac {\sqrt 6}{2}$ as  the answer. However, using $8$ $ln|sec \frac {x}{2}|$ gives the number $8$ $ln \frac {2} {\sqrt 6}$.

Now, $-8$ $ln \frac {\sqrt 6}{2} $ and $8$ $ln \frac {2} {\sqrt 6}$ have the same value. So, the confusion is clear. And yes, as you have stated the relations, they should be equal to each other. I made a slight error when inputting the numbers in the calculator and was getting different results. 
Thank you for the answer.